# Python: "Import Script" greyed out

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.1

I have a tool that I created from a Python script which I update from time to time. Usually I will right-click the tool and choose Import Script, but lately this has been unavailable, as shown below:

[image]

This has been happening to almost all the tools I create, usually after a few imports. The problem is that if the script is cached the only workaround is to create a whole new interface, which can be pretty time-consuming.

Does anyone know why this happens?

I found this post on the Esri forums describing the same problem:
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/70829-Python-Import-Script-grayed-out

Comment: Do you have a strong need to import the script into the tools cache?  Why not just allow the ArcGIS script tool to point to the script (on disk) itself.  Unless it is for portability or to "hide" the script from a user, there is no need to "Import Script"...

Comment: I don't theoretically need to import the script, but sometimes it will become cached anyway (that is, making changes to the .py file doesn't affect the behavior of the script) and my way of "resetting" it is to use the Import Script function.

Comment: I've never seen Python scripts get cached using the method @RyanDalton suggests so would recommend using that rather than Import Script which seems to be for [**Embedding scripts and password protecting tools**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005700000017000000)

Comment: I rebuilt the tool without importing and it seems to be working better, so maybe that is the way to go. Thanks guys. I still don't understand though what would make the Import Script option disappear like that (suppose I did need to embed the script, for example). Anyone from Esri listening? :)

Answer (score 1):

The question has been answered in Geonet:

> you need to export script and then you gonna be able to add a new script... Don't overwrite the script you want to import.

https://geonet.esri.com/message/414853#414853

Comment: Could you link to the source?

Comment: https://geonet.esri.com/message/414853#414853

Answer (score 0):

In your Comment you ask if anyone from Esri is listening.

Although a number of Esri staff are regular users of this site, I suspect each will be focussed on their own area(s) of expertise.

Consequently, if this issue is still of concern to you then I think that you should submit this to your local **[Esri Support](http://support.esri.com/en/)**.  However, before doing that I recommend that you try to have it in a reproducible form.